# Using portable imagemagick convert program

Tags: c#, windows, shell, imagemagick, cmd

How do I pass image filepaths to convert.exe, given I know all the file paths?

ImageMagick is NOT installed, but just in my project folder. I don't think I'm supposed to pass the image filepaths through a cmd prompt.

Here is my current attempt. I get no errors from it -- but a cmd prompt pops up quickly and disappears quickly -- I've printed the screen when it's up and [it's saying something about userparams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uMq1.jpg)... which apparently has to do with ImageMagick somehow.

When I run the same command directly in a command prompt without Unity (which is what I'm using to run the code below), I get the following:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

    F:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>F:\ImageMagickTest\ImageMagick\convert.e
    xe F:\ImageMagickTest\PDFs\Appointment.pdf F:\ImageMagickTest\ConvertedPDFs\Appo
    intment.png
    Unrecoverable error: rangecheck in .setuserparams
    Operand stack:
        --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--
    START 0 2588256 1246519 1476808 192904 true 1139 5 <3>
    END PROCS 0 2588256 1257818 1476808 194288 true 1138 5 <3>
    gs_std_e.ps 0 2608352 1263873 1496904 199000 true 1138 5 <6>
    gs_il1_e.ps 0 2608352 1266056 1496904 199000 true 1138 5 <9>
    END FONTDIR/ENCS 0 2608352 1266234 1496904 199000 true 1138 5 <15>
    END DEVS 0 2611856 1273266 1496904 199000 true 1138 5 <15>
    END STATD 0 2611856 1280422 1496904 200624 true 1138 5 <39>
    END GS_FONTS 0 2641800 1309596 1496904 200624 true 1139 5 <45>
    END BASIC COLOR 15 2661896 1319485 1496904 200624 true 1137 5 <48>
    END LEVEL 1 COLOR 15 2661896 1321213 1496904 200624 true 1137 5 <51>
    END IMAGE 15 2661896 1324515 1496904 200624 true 1137 5 <54>
    gs_btokn.ps 15 2661896 1327957 1496904 200624 true 996 4 <57>
    gs_dps1.ps 15 2661896 1329302 1496904 200624 true 996 4 <57>
    gs_dps2.ps 15 2661896 1331309 1496904 200624 true 996 4 <57>
    gs_type1.ps 15 2681992 1336187 1496904 200624 true 996 4 <57>
    While reading gs_lev2.ps:
    %%[ Error: invalidaccess; OffendingCommand: put ]%%
    START 322159 2736608 1402076 1496904 202880 true 1000 7 <92>
    END PROCS 322159 2756704 1416711 1496904 204264 true 998 7 <92>
    gs_std_e.ps 322159 2756704 1419438 1496904 205648 true 998 7 <95>
    gs_il1_e.ps 322159 2756704 1421621 1496904 205648 true 998 7 <98>
    END FONTDIR/ENCS 322159 2756704 1421799 1496904 205648 true 998 7 <104>
    END DEVS 322159 2760208 1428831 1496904 205648 true 998 7 <104>
    END STATD 322159 2780304 1439315 1496904 207272 true 998 7 <128>
    END GS_FONTS 322159 2800400 1466811 1496904 207272 true 998 7 <134>
    END BASIC COLOR 322159 2820496 1476700 1496904 207272 true 996 7 <137>
    END LEVEL 1 COLOR 322159 2820496 1478428 1496904 207272 true 996 7 <140>
    END IMAGE 322159 2820496 1481730 1496904 207272 true 996 7 <143>
    gs_btokn.ps 322159 2820496 1485172 1496904 207272 true 996 7 <146>
    gs_dps1.ps 322159 2820496 1486517 1496904 207272 true 996 7 <146>
    gs_dps2.ps 322159 2820496 1488524 1496904 207272 true 996 7 <146>
    gs_type1.ps 322159 2820496 1490098 1496904 207272 true 996 7 <146>
    While reading gs_lev2.ps:
    %%[ Error: invalidaccess; OffendingCommand: put ]%%

    F:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>
```

Anyway, as stated, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code in the software that's causing the same problem:

```
    string currDir = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    string convertPath = currDir + @"\ImageMagick\convert.exe";
    string convertedDir = currDir + @"\ConvertedPDFs\";
    string pdfFolder = currDir + @"\PDFs\";
    string fileName = "Appointment";
    //System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(currDir + @"\" + convertedDirName);
    string argumentForImageMagick;


    argumentForImageMagick = pdfFolder + fileName + ".pdf" + " " + convertedDir + fileName + ".png";
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo {Arguments = argumentForImageMagick , FileName = convertPath};
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info).WaitForExit();
```

When I print the argument and filepath for the ProcessStartInfo instance, I get

```
F:\ImageMagickTest\PDFs\Appointment.pdf
F:\ImageMagickTest\ConvertedPDFs\Appointment.png
```

for the argument, and

```
F:\ImageMagickTest\ImageMagick\convert.exe
```

for the filepath.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918207/how-to-use-imagemagick-with-c-sharp) is the same question.

Comment: Hmm...It looks similar, but I'm not really understanding, still, how to do this. I've updated the question with my fresh attempt.

Comment: If you print out (or stop with a debugger and examine) the strings that get assigned to **Arguments** and **FileName** in the **ProcessStartInfo** instance what do you see?

Comment: Ah! Excellent information to have, good point. Added to the original question.

Comment: Also added a link to a screenshot of the error that pops up lightning quick in a cmd prompt.

Comment: And (forgive me for asking the obvious) I take it the images and executable do exist at those locations? Assuming they are, what happens if you run the command directly from a command shell? >F:\ImageMagickTest\ImageMagick\convert.exe F:\ImageMagickTest\PDFs\Appointment.pdf F:\ImageMagickTest\ConvertedPDFs\Appointment.png

Comment: Ok, thanks, scott, now I've got the complete error message from a cmd prompt. Not sure what it means, though. I assume it's got something to do with the way imagemagick is trying to access the file? Yes, the pdf does exist, with the exact same path -- same with convert.exe. The error I'm getting in the cmd prompt indicates something with "images" and "fonts" is going on, so I assume that's imagemagick attempting to handle a pdf...what do you reckon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out part of the problem -- I had to have Ghostscript installed. This doesn't work for me, as I can't install any software on the host computer...but I guess now I know what was wrong! Thanks.

My next question is basically whether I can run ghostscript without installing it on a host computer...